# Upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04 fails. The package 'postgresql-10-postgis-2.4'

Tags: apt, 18.04, 20.04, upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade 18.04 to 20.04 but the upgrade halts with error:
ERROR Dist-upgrade failed: 'The package 'postgresql-10-postgis-2.4' is marked for removal but it is in the removal blacklist.
postgresql-10 and  postgis-2.4 is our current versions.
When searching fot this error I found a bug report 1907652 dealing with this problem, but it looks like it is work in progress
Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: The version of PostgreSQL in 18.04 is quite different from the one in 20.04. *Ideally*, you would need to uninstall PostgreSQL completely, removing the data directories and configuration directories, then upgrade the OS, then re-install the database and restore from backups. Do note that you'll want to do a bunch of testing on those databases to ensure the schema is compatible with the newer version of PostgreSQL, as some data types have evolved or been deprecated.